# Sorting An Array By Key Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [lastUpload] => [lastPost] => Sun Nov 23 2014 16:54:13 [username] => blt152561 [email] => user1@mail.com [joined] => Sun Nov 23 2014 16:49:09 [prodCount] => 2 [mediaCount] => 0 [userId] => 77292aaf-e540-465c-9319-8dd74c8d7f12 ) [1] => Array ( [lastUpload] => [lastPost] => [username] => mvbg40 [email] => user2@mail.com [joined] => Sun Nov 23 2014 9:31:43 [prodCount] => 0 [mediaCount] => 0 [userId] => a2998c68-1c9a-49b9-8c78-ced3cffaa109 ) [2] => Array ( [lastUpload] => Sun Nov 23 2014 7:54:03 [lastPost] => Sun Nov 23 2014 7:53:53 [username] => flexingladies [email] => user5@mail.com [joined] => Sun Nov 23 2014 7:47:44 [prodCount] => 1 [mediaCount] => 1 [userId] => 3b4b6aad-de95-428c-95ed-cb4fe963f322 ) [3] => Array ( [lastUpload] => [lastPost] => Sat Nov 22 2014 8:05:30 [username] => dewey [email] => user3@mail.com [joined] => Sat Nov 22 2014 8:02:01 [prodCount] => 1 [mediaCount] => 0 [userId] => 08220286-6a24-49ff-929b-ccb4e0e10c3e ) [4] => Array ( [lastUpload] => [lastPost] => Thu Nov 20 2014 18:43:56 [username] => mhirsen99 [email] => user4@mail.com [joined] => Thu Nov 20 2014 18:43:09 [prodCount] => 1 [mediaCount] => 0 [userId] => ddea4f04-b035-4e8d-a777-cb4a2813b705 ) )
```

Which I would like to sort by the value in lastPost.

I have no idea how to go about doing this. Can someone point me in the right direction? I tried ksort but its simply returning 1 and not the sorted array.

Comment: Just search over stackoverflow

Comment: or [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use foreach to make this work :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  $ordered[$value['lastPost']] = $value;

ksort($ordered, SORT_ASC);
```

Comment: This kinda worked, however for some reason those that don't have the ['lastPost'] key are scattered in the results and should all be at the bottom / top depending on sort no?

Comment: You can make use of !empty(), isset() or array_key_exists() for not allowing them to include in sorted array http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
asort($array);
```

to sort the arrays in ascending order, according to the value

or

```
arsort($array) ;
```

to sort the arrays in descending order, according to the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort for custom sorting by key

`usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $a['lastPost'] - $b['lastPost']; });`